# Change motd value in UNIX Operating System

Tags: scripting, motd

I need to change the value of MOTD using a script but I do not know how I should start. Am attaching sample MOTD.

[image]

Comment: Which unix variant (e.g. which distribution if Linux)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a MOTD in the style you're showing in your example you'll likely want to make use of the `banner` command. You can feed it the output from the `hostname` command to get a nice banner of your server's name.

To make this your MOTD you'll simply want to direct the output from these command to the file `/etc/motd`, which is what's used for displaying the MOTD.

```
$ ...cmd... > /etc/motd
```

**NOTE:** The commands I'm going to show below can be swapped into `...cmd...`.

#### Example

```
$ banner $(hostname)

 #####   ######   #######  #######  #     #  #######   #####    #####   
#     #  #     #  #        #        ##    #  #        #     #  #     #  
#        #     #  #        #        # #   #  #        #        #        
#  ####  ######   #####    #####    #  #  #  #####    #  ####  #  ####  
#     #  #   #    #        #        #   # #  #        #     #  #     #  
#     #  #    #   #        #        #    ##  #        #     #  #     #  
 #####   #     #  #######  #######  #     #  #######   #####    #####
```

This one liner will give you nearly what you want:

```
$ (banner "server"; \
    printf "Hostname: %s\nDate    : %s\nUptime  :%s\n\n", \
    "$(hostname -s)" "$(date)" "$(uptime)")

 #####   #######  ######   #     #  #######  ######   
#     #  #        #     #  #     #  #        #     #  
#        #        #     #  #     #  #        #     #  
 #####   #####    ######   #     #  #####    ######   
      #  #        #   #     #   #   #        #   #    
#     #  #        #    #     # #    #        #    #   
 #####   #######  #     #     #     #######  #     #  

Hostname: greeneggs
Date    : Thu Apr 24 22:39:23 EDT 2014
Uptime  : 22:39:23 up 3 days,  8:34,  6 users,  load average: 0.80, 1.06, 1.49
```

#### Printing boxes

In addition to using the command line tool `banner` to print banner text, you can use another helper tool called [`boxes`](http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/) to wrap a box around arbitrary text.

```
$ boxes -d shell -p a1l2 <(hostname -s)
##############
#            #
#  greeneggs #
#            #
##############
```

We can use this approach and scale it up to do what you want like so:

```
$ boxes -d shell -p a1l2 \
    <(banner "server"; \
        printf "Hostname: %s\nDate    : %s\nUptime  :%s\n" \
        "$(hostname -s)" "$(date)" "$(uptime)")
###################################################################################
#                                                                                 #
#                                                                                 #
#   #####   #######  ######   #     #  #######  ######                            #
#  #     #  #        #     #  #     #  #        #     #                           #
#  #        #        #     #  #     #  #        #     #                           #
#   #####   #####    ######   #     #  #####    ######                            #
#        #  #        #   #     #   #   #        #   #                             #
#  #     #  #        #    #     # #    #        #    #                            #
#   #####   #######  #     #     #     #######  #     #                           #
#                                                                                 #
#  Hostname: greeneggs                                                            #
#  Date    : Thu Apr 24 22:54:09 EDT 2014                                         #
#  Uptime  : 22:54:09 up 3 days,  8:49,  6 users,  load average: 0.63, 0.81, 1.09 #
#                                                                                 #
###################################################################################
```

Comment: Hi slm, thanks it works, however i do not have the boxes tool, is there something like that i can use in aix?  Many Thanks

Comment: @zieggy - no idea. I would installed boxes or manually make a box myself and print the contents inside of it.

Comment: thanks, generally answers my concern, will try to check how can i do the boxes!

Comment: Is this dynamic ? Will the output change each time a user has logged in?

Comment: @GC13 - No, the date and uptime etc change every time the above command is run and written to /etc/motd. You need to create a cron job if you want this file to get periodically updated.

Comment: Agree that it can be done using cron job. However, if I want to execute as a script dynamically, how can I do that?

For example, I tried to use the above command in /etc/update-motd.d/01-mymotd.

Here, 01-mymotd is a file created by me, and when I tried to execute it, I am getting "run part" error.

However, the same command works when executed from another shell script.

Thanks.

Comment: @GC13 - that error makes me think that since you're on Ubuntu there are commands within the example above that doesn't run in dash (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). When run in your shell you're probably using Bash so it works. Try running the above with /bin/sh instead to see if it works there as well.

Comment: @slm, I am using /bin/sh in 00-header under /etc/update-motd.d/.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate dynamic MOTD, check out this up to date guide

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/

Basically, you have to

1) create /etc/update-motd.d

2) place your script there

Comment: Please don't answer with 'check out this link'. Try to make the answer self-contained describing all necessary steps in details. Then just leave a link for a source at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`motd` is simply a file. From `man motd`:

```
NAME
       motd - message of the day

DESCRIPTION
       The  contents  of  /etc/motd  are  displayed by login(1) after a successful
       login but just before it executes the login shell.

      The abbreviation "motd" stands for "message of the day", and this file has
      been traditionally used for exactly that (it requires much less disk space
      than mail to all users).

FILES
      /etc/motd
```

As a script point of view, something as simple as that would be enough:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "     Welcome to $(hostname -s)\n\n" > /etc/motd
```

Comment: Hi Ouki, thanks, but i wanted to replace the content of the motd using a script, i forgot to say that the banner word "SERVER" should be the HOSTNAME of the lpar.

Comment: More dynamic `motd` messages are OS dependent. What is your OS/distrib?

Comment: Hi, my OS is AIX `7.1`

Comment: How can i make the hostname will become a banner?