# How do I create a dark blue text on a bright white background in MOTD in Debian?

Tags: debian, colors, motd

This is what I currently have. It displays black on bright white. However, I want to have blue (0;34m) on bright white.

```
^[[0;7;34;37;5mWelcome!^[[0m
```

I used [this website](http://www.mewbies.com/how_to_customize_your_console_login_message_tutorial.htm#ccchart) as a reference, but I did not manage to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<Esc>[34;47mWelcome!<Esc>[m`

Comment: also, use ctrl-v in vi to insert esc.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. It worked. Why does it work? I don't understand the logic of the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/motd` file is *data* (cannot contain a script, such as "`echo -e`"), and is presented to all logins irregardless of their actual terminal type.  While you *can* do this for some configurations, the usual recommendation is that `/etc/motd` should be plain text (no escape sequences) because:

- attempting to print colored text does not take into account *whether* the user's terminal can display the escape sequences,
- the colors do not take into account the current (or default) foreground and background colors of the terminal, and
- do not take into account that some logins may translate nonprinting characters to "readable" form.

If you really want to do this, you should be aware that

- getting a particular background color depends upon the terminal,
- the *text background* color is not necessarily the same (or even close) to the terminal's *default background* color,
- some terminals color erased areas of the screen, such as when clearing the screen, using the current "ANSI colors", while other terminals do not.

Further reading:

- [Bold text and change color of text for MOTD in nano on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771199/bold-text-and-change-color-of-text-for-motd-in-nano-on-osx)
- [Is it possible to put commands in /etc/motd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/459229/is-it-possible-to-put-commands-in-etc-motd)
- [Change motd value in UNIX Operating System](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126423/change-motd-value-in-unix-operating-system)
- [How do I use colors in the MOTD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139056/how-do-i-use-colors-in-the-motd)
- [No colour in MOTD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223921/no-colour-in-motd)
- [My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation and references. I cannot upvote your answer yet since I do not have enough reputation on this website.

Comment: But you can mark it "accepted" if it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise *not* following those instructions.  The motd is presented to all interactive logins, **regardless of terminal type**.  This means that embedding control characters in the output is going to be wrong for at least one user, at least once.

If you feel you really must, then use `tput` to generate the correct codes for the user's terminal.  That's much safer.  For blue on white, use

```
tput setaf 4; tput setab 7
```